Powershell Invoke-WebRequest - IE Security popup
I have the script below that was given to me by a Barracuda engineer.
I run it on the command line and it works but it gives me two Internet Explorer popups, to add trusted web sites, I just click 'Close' and it continues and works.
That's fine for one run, but I want 500 iterations in a loop .
The popups come with these lines
$response.Forms[0].Fields["username"] = $username
$response.Forms[0].Fields["password"] = $password

I have tried to use -UseBasicParsing wherever I have a Invoke-WebRequest but I get an error:
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:1
+ $response.Forms[0].Fields["username"] = $username

Is there a way I can change up this script so that I supply the creds in a header or something? I don't actually follow what each step of this script is doing. But once we get to line 30 .. the rest is fine ...
Line 30 gives me the successful connection and line 34 allows me to run the api call I need.
Basically, you have to login via the web site to use the api.
$janusUrl = "https://eastus2.cloudbackup.barracudanetworks.com/"
$account = "19191919"
$username = "myusername"
$password = "mypassword"
$response = try { Invoke-WebRequest $janusUrl -SessionVariable janusSession -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } catch { $_.Exception.Response }
$correlationCookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie
$correlationCookie.Domain = ([System.Uri]$janusUrl).Host
$response.Headers.'Set-Cookie'.Split(";") | ForEach-Object {
    $kvp = $_.Split("=")
    switch ($kvp[0].Trim())
    {
        'expires' { $correlationCookie.Expires = Get-Date -Date $kvp[1] }
        'path' { $correlationCookie.Path = $kvp[1] }
        'secure' { $correlationCookie.Secure = $true }
        'httponly' { $correlationCookie.HttpOnly = $true }
        default 
        {
            if ($kvp[0].StartsWith(".AspNetCore.Correlation")) {
                $correlationCookie.Name = $kvp[0]
                $correlationCookie.Value = $kvp[1]
            }
        }
    }
}
$janusSession.MaximumRedirection = 2
$response = Invoke-WebRequest  $response.Headers.Location -WebSession $janusSession
$response.Forms[0].Fields["username"] = $username
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $response.Forms[0].Action -Method POST -Body $response.Forms[0].Fields -WebSession $janusSession
$response.Forms[0].Fields["password"] = $password
$response = try { Invoke-WebRequest $response.Forms[0].Action -Method POST -Body $response.Forms[0].Fields -WebSession $janusSession } catch { $_.Exception.Response }
$janusSession.Cookies.Add($correlationCookie)
$janusSession.MaximumRedirection = -1
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $response.ResponseUri -WebSession $janusSession
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($janusUrl + "api/v2/accounts/" + $account + "/connections") -WebSession $janusSession
foreach ($connection in $response.connectionsList)
{
    Write-Host $connection
}

